# Track the changes of attributes for a key column and populate into an interim table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have employee table with scdType2 as laoding technique( Empid is the keycolumn). 
I need to track the changes of attributes(Reporting_To) for a key column and populate into an interim table.

Existing rec in Employee table with Empid as keycolumn

```
Empid |Project | Reporting_To |Valid_From | Valid_Upto | Creation_Date | Modification_Date
------------------------------------------------------------------------
123456 |ABC | 123 |01-Jan-2017 | 31-Dec-9999 | 01-Jan-2017
```

As part of incremental(file dated 28-May-2017), I got a record with same Empid as:

```
Empid | Project | Reporting_To | Valid_From | Valid_Upto
--------------------------------------------------------
123456 | DEF | 123 |28-May-2017 | 31-Dec-9999
```

Hence my Employee table will be updated with Scd2 logic as below:

```
Empid | Project | Reporting_To | Valid_From | Valid_Upto | Creation_Date | Modification_Date
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123456 |ABC | 123 | 01-Jan-2017 | 27-May-2017 | 01-Jan-2017 | 28-May-2017 
123456 |DEF | 123 | 28-May-2017 | 31-Dec-9999 | 28-May-2017
```

Here change in Project hence Scd2. 
But as there is no update in Reporting_To, there would not be any entry into interim table

As part of incremental(file dated 29-May-2017), I got a record with same Empid as:

```
Empid |Project | Reporting_To | Valid_From | Valid_Upto
-------------------------------------------------------
123456 |DEF | 589 | 30-May-2017 | 31-Dec-9999
```

Hence my Employee table will be updated with Scd2 logic as below:

```
Empid | Project | Reporting_To |Valid_From | Valid_Upto | Creation_Date | Modification_Date
------------------------------------------------------------------------
123456 |ABC | 123 | 01-Jan-2017 |27-May-2017 | 01-Jan-2017 | 28-May-2017
123456 |DEF | 123 | 28-May-2017 |29-May-2017 |28-May-2017 |29-May-2017
123456 |DEF | 589 | 30-May-2017 |31-Dec-9999 | 29-May-2017
```

As there is update in Reporting_To, there would be an entry in interim table as:

```
Empid |Reporting_To |Valid_From |Valid_Upto
-------------------------------------------
123456 | 589 | 30-May-2017 | 31-Dec-9999
```

Please help me with a query for tracking change in Reporting_To, picking required values from employee table and loading them into interim table

Answer (score 0):

you can use select with group by Empid and Reporting_To

```
select * from Employee group by Empid, Reporting_To;
```

Comment: @Zaki, I need a query for tracking if changes happened in Reporting_To or not. And if changes happened on this column, I need to load into another table.

Comment: @Zaki, I need to track for these changes after whole processing is done, not during the processing. That is the challenge and hence not able to use trigger.

Comment: Ok, you can use a trigger after any update or insert done on employee table in this trigger get the count of select * from Employee group by Empid, Reporting_To; and save it in database then compare it with old value if it greater than old so change on this column happen

Comment: Or use it without trigger

Comment: which SQL database engine you use?

Comment: Am using SQLDeveloper

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this without trigger. Because we are not allowed to create trigger in our project. It is client's requirement. Is there any way to achieve this through query?

Comment: are you use java or oracle forms as backend develope?